# Как сделать так чтобы слова из файла выводились русскими буквами

Tags: python, файлы

В общем, при работе с файлом программа выводит случайное слово из файла со словами, но из-за проблем с кириллицей выводится непонятно что.

Код ниже:

```
import random

def charCount(word):
    dict = {}
    for i in word:
        dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
    return dict
  
  
def possible_words(lwords, charSet):
    for word in lwords:
        flag = 1
        chars = charCount(word)
        for key in chars:
            if key not in charSet:
                flag = 0
            else:
                if charSet.count(key) != chars[key]:
                    flag = 0
        if flag == 1:
            print(word)

with open("words.txt") as f:
    input = f.read().splitlines() #создаем список с элементами через enter;

charSet = list(random.choice(input))
print(charSet)
possible_words(input, charSet)
```

Выводится это: ['Р', 'і', 'С', 'ѓ', 'Р', 'ґ', 'С', '‹']

> РіСѓРґС‹

Comment: в какой кодировке файл? Нужно указать при открытии нужную кодировку

Comment: Сам файл в UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать кодировку

```
with open("words.txt", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
```

*PS. Не нужно использовать слова `dict` и `input` как имена переменных. Это встроенные функции языка.*